# bash: python: .py: command not found

Tags: python, bash, qiime

I am trying to run the following command in `QIIME2 virtual machine`, installed on macbook but the code is not working

```
validate_mapping_file.py -m Fasting_Map.txt -o mapping_output
```

Here is the link: http://qiime.org/tutorials/tutorial.html

I get the following message

> bash: validate_mapping_file.py: command not found

I am new to `unix/linux` as well as on `qiime`. I would be very thankful for the help...

Comment: `chmod +x validate_mapping_file.py` plus please show the first line of this Python file - does it have a shabang line?

Comment: Did you try using `./validate_mapping_file.py` or `<absolute_path> to validate_mapping_file.py`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To execute a Python script in this way, you need three things:

1. The file needs to have the executable bit set for you. To do this, try using: `chmod u+x validate_mapping_file.py`
2. The file needs to begin with a shebang, for example `#!/usr/bin/env python3` which will tell the system to run the script using the python3 executable according to your environment
3. The file needs to be in one of the directories in your `PATH` environment variable. You can add the current directory using export `PATH=$PWD:$PATH` or use `./validate_mapping_file.py` instead of just `validate_mapping_file.py` (thanks @Grisha)

Afterwards you should be able to execute the script the way you tried before.

Comment: ... plus it has to be in one of the `PATH` directories

Comment: ```$(pwd):$PATH```, or its backtick-based equivalent, is extremely inefficient compared to `$PWD/$PATH`; like any other command substitution, it forks a subshell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I doubt that he types faster than `pwd` executes. Still, it achieves the same and is more efficient, so I editted the answer.

Comment: @FlorianRhiem, thank you. The concern isn't so much immediate interactive use, but not teaching practices that would create a bottleneck if used in other circumstances (ie. inside an inner loop).

Comment: And you need to have Python installed.